# Coldfusion Server Side Gauge Charts?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

We have a task that goes through data on our server every night and produces PDF files with the information.

The client wants to be able to add either linear gauges or radial gauges(speedometers) to these charts. However with CF8.0.1 and it's limited WebCharts3d we can't do this nativly. I've tried the fix to print radial gauges that Ray Camden posted but I'm unable to save the chart created.

I need the chart created and saved on the server as a PNG without needing a clients machine. And suggestions?

Again we're running ColdFusion 8.0.1

Comment: Can you elaborate on "unable to save the chart created"? I know the example you were looking at, and it does work with CF8, so I am trying to figure out what issue you had with it.

Comment: Instead of trying to use the ancient WebCharts3D, you could probably just buy a solution. Look for any Java-based charting library.

Comment: I'm giving JFreeCharts a go currently. I've been able to produce fairly solid results. It appears their Meter/Gauge charts are on the low end of their support and update priority, but it's been good enough so far.